# D-Day Counter Java

Tags: java, android

I am trying to develop an android app that displays how many years, months, and days left for the future date specified. However, I am getting wield values :/

Here, the remaining year, month, and days until 2018/06/18 are calculated: calculating remaining months were quite difficulty since each month can have different number of days. So I believe I made an mistake while trying to obtaining remaining months. However, my result was frustrating: I got 41 years, 01 months, negative wield value days...

```
public void countDownStart() {
    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            long diff;
            long years=0;
            long months=0;
            long  days=0;
            long temp_days=0;
            int current_month;

            Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
            futureDate.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 18);
            futureDate.set(Calendar.MONTH, 6);
            futureDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2018);
            Calendar referenceDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();

            if (futureDate.after(currentDate)) {
                diff = futureDate.getTimeInMillis() - currentDate.getTimeInMillis();
                days = diff/(1000*60*60*24);
                years = diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365);
                diff = diff - years * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365;
                months = 0;
                boolean flag = true;
                current_month = referenceDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                while (flag) {
                    switch (current_month) {
                        case 0:
                        case 2:
                        case 4:
                        case 6:
                        case 7:
                        case 9:
                        case 11:
                            diff = diff - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            diff = diff - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 28;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                        case 5:
                        case 8:
                        case 10:
                            diff = diff - 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31;
                            break;
                    }
                    months = months + 1;
                    referenceDate.add(Calendar.MONTH, 1);
                    current_month=referenceDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    temp_days = diff / 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

                    if (temp_days <= 31) {
                        int next_month = referenceDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int days_in_month;

                        if (next_month == 0 || next_month == 2 || next_month == 4 || next_month == 6 ||
                                next_month == 7 || next_month == 9 || next_month == 11) {
                            days_in_month = 31;
                        } else if (next_month == 1) {
                            days_in_month = 28;
                        } else {
                            days_in_month = 30;
                        }

                        if (temp_days < days_in_month) {
                            flag = false;
                            //days = temp_days;
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            else
            {
                years=0;
                months=0;
                days=0;
            }
            txtTimerYear.setText(""+String.format("%02d",years));
            txtTimerMonth.setText(""+String.format("%02d",months));
            txtTimerDay.setText(""+String.format("%03d",days));

        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,1*1000);
}
```

}

I would really appreciate your help!!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. It has methods that give you directly remaining months, days, etc. And it pays attention to the months that have 30 or 31 days.